# how to use variable in sql script for postgres database

Tags: postgresql, docker

I working on python project using docker and docker-compose. I using `postgres` as backend database.

I need to create few tables and initialize them with some data on startup. For that I using a `sql script` which runs with docker-compose as

```
# docker-compose.yml
 volumes:
      - postgres_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - queries.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/queries.sql
```

```
# queries.sql

-- Create table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
    id          serial primary key,
    address  varchar(2000)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account (
    id          serial primary key,
    email  varchar(2000)
);


-- Define variables and constants
SET SOME_VAR = 'abcd';  # varchar


-- Define queries
INSERT INTO person (address)
    VALUES (SOME_VAR);

INSERT INTO account (email)
    VALUES (SOME_VAR);
```

As I have the same value used in multiple queries, so I am trying to set a variable and use it in all queries.

But on running,I am getting error on line `SET SOME_VAR = 'abcd';` as below

```
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "some_var"
```

I tried using following

- @ symbol
- DECLARE keyword

but none of them worked.

what I am missing?

Comment: Is the SQL script being run by `psql`?

Comment: [SET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) can't be used that way, it for changing existing run time settings. Best I can think of at the moment are: 1) Create a temporary table and populate with variable names and values and pull from that. 2) Use [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) to create anonymous function and set variable and do inserts inside it.

Comment: Hi jjanes,Thanks. I am using official postgres docker image, when this container gets up, that script gets executed.

Comment: Hi Adrian, Thanks. `DO` with `BEGIN` and `END`  did the job.